# Storing and Graphing results of API queried via Python.

Tags: python, graph, analytics, monitoring

I am querying our systems for certain data, the data is returned as XML and i can count the value of a field. I need a way to be able to store it and then draw graphs from it.

So far my research has shown me to tools like Kibnana, Graphite etc.

I just need a few suggestions for a simple tool that can graph this periodic data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other options:

[Grafana](https://grafana.com/) - Visualizer of data. It can read data at least from prometheus, graphite and elastics. Its primary goal is to visualize things in user defined dashboards and correlate things from possibly various sources. It's simpler then Elasticsearch.

[Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) - Complex monitoring solution including data gathering, data archiving (trends, compaction,…), visualizer with dashboards, alerting and some management support for alerts escalations.

Another option will be to save the data to a database (as Postgres or MySQL) and create a web page that embeds a visualization library as [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) to display the graphs.